# Keyboard key "s" not triggered

Tags: linux, x11, keyboard, xfce, keyboard-event

I recently installed XFCE over my arch - used gnome before.
After some time using XFCE i discovered that my keypress "s" does not work as expected (works first in XFCE without problems).

Output of `xev` if i press "s" is following:

```
FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  70  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Output of `xev` if i press "Shift" + "s" is like it should be:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x1ec, subw 0x0, time 1860946, (-385,-70), root:(2406,438),
    state 0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x1ec, subw 0x0, time 1861443, (-385,-70), root:(2406,438),
    state 0x11, keycode 39 (keysym 0x53, S), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (53) "S"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (53) "S"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x1ec, subw 0x0, time 1861535, (-385,-70), root:(2406,438),
    state 0x11, keycode 39 (keysym 0x53, S), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (53) "S"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x1ec, subw 0x0, time 1862401, (-385,-70), root:(2406,438),
    state 0x11, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

As soon as i change to gnome or boot into windows "s" is working like before.

- Keyboard is Razor Ultimate 2016 - de-CH Layout
- Keyboard layout (German(Switzerland)) in XFCE Setting is correct
- Keyboard model is "Generic 105 key PC (intl)"
- no application shortcut is bound to "s"

I would say the key press "s" i now bound to another thing - but how to discover or where to change this behavior?

Maybe this is a needed hint: if i try to set an keyboard shortcut (xfce4-keyboard-settings) to the key "s" - it can not be done!
"s" press will be recognized (blinks on press), but keypress can't be bound..

Additional: if i try to set an keyboard shortcut to the window manager - the key "s" will be recognized and can be bound - but the execution will not be triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it out by myself:

The problem was that I had added a custom keyboard shortcut for `xfce4-terminal --drop-down` on the key `§` (on us layout it is the key "tilde") which gets saved in config as `<property name="section" type="string" value="xfce4-terminal --drop-down"/>`

If I remove this shortcut (or edit it to `Super + §`), everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

1. You actually do have a shortcut bound to "s" , and I will bet it just so happens to be bound to nothing.

You can find this out by going into ~/.config/xfce4 and running:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'strings -f {} | grep "value=\"\""' \;
```

and this will print out all the xfconf lines that have empty `value=""`. If you don't find it in `~/.config/xfce4` you should try:

`sudo find . -iname '*keyboard*' -exec sh -c 'strings -f {} | grep "value=\"\""' \;`

to find it ,in case it is not user-based but 'hardcoded' in /etc

Comment: thank you for the suggestion! sadly it's not found in any config files (searched by 'value=""'). maybe this is a needed hint: if i try to set an keyboardshortcut to the key "s" - it can not be done - "s" press will be recognized (blinks on press), but keypress can't be bound..